# eBay API UploadSiteHostedPictures call gives wrong error

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, ebay-api

I am using php and cURL to interact with the eBay api.

Here is the long error message I get when I try to upload an image using the eBay api and UploadSiteHostedPictures:

> The API call "GeteBayOfficialTime" is invalid or not supported in this
>   release.

Full errors object:

> object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (5) { ["ShortMessage"]=> string(21)
>   "Unsupported API call." ["LongMessage"]=> string(79) "The API call
>   "GeteBayOfficialTime" is invalid or not supported in this release."
>   ["ErrorCode"]=> string(1) "2" ["SeverityCode"]=> string(5) "Error"
>   ["ErrorClassification"]=> string(12) "RequestError" }

That doesn't make sense because I wans't calling GeteBayOfficialTime. Here is my code. I obviously have replaced sensitive data.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml .= '<UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
$xml .= '<RequesterCredentials>';
$xml .= '<eBayAuthToken>my token</eBayAuthToken>';
$xml .= '</RequesterCredentials>';
$xml .= '<ExternalPictureURL>http://www.website.com/randompicture.jpg</ExternalPictureURL>';
$xml .= '<PictureName>My Picture Name</PictureName>';
$xml .= '</UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest>';

$headers = array(
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 929',
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME : UploadSiteHostedPictures',
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:hidden',
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:hidden',
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:hidden',
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0',
    'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8'
);

$session  = curl_init('https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$responsexml = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);         
$response = new SimpleXMLElement($responsexml);
var_dump($response);
```

I've run the same request with the API test tool and it works fine with no errors - https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/default.aspx

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake. The headers cannot have spaces between the key and the value.

```
$headers = array(
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:929',
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:UploadSiteHostedPictures',
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:hidden',
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:hidden',
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:hidden',
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID:0',
    'Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8'
);
```